# How to call multiple methods at same time?

Tags: java

I am trying to call some methods in a method and storing in different different List for further use in same method. So, is it possible to call all at same time. Here is codes:

```
List<Student> students = studentMao.getAll(collegeId);
List<Department> departments = departmentsMao.getByCollegeId(collegeId);
List<College> colleges = collegeMao.getByUniversityId(universityId);
```

Please any suggestion

Comment: you can wrap them under one method and call it...

Comment: Depends. You could create separate threads each calling a method and storing the result.

Comment: What do you mean by "same time"? Single statement? Same execution start time?

Comment: Means, all methods call should be simultaneously or Same execution start time.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you require the methods to run simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run all three methods concurrently you can use `Executor` to run concurrent threads, and wait for the result thanks to `Future`. Something like:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
Future<List<Student>> studentsFuture = executor.submit(() -> return studentMao.getAll(collegeId));
Future<List<Department>> departmentsFuture = executor.submit(() -> return departmentsMao.getByCollegeId(collegeId));
Future<List<College>> collegesFuture = executor.submit(() -> return collegeMao.getByUniversityId(universityId));

List<Student> students = studentsFuture.get();
List<Department> departments = departmentsFuture.get();
List<College> colleges = collegesFuture.get();
```

Get waits until the current task running in another threads finishes, so this piece of code will finish when all the concurrent threads have finished.